# Running diff in Magit, filtered to only some specific files

Tags: magit, diff

I’m basically trying to run this command, but in Magit:

```
git diff master..17 -- "**/*.scala"
```

… i.e. to view changes in all `*.scala` files between `ref/heads/master` and `ref/heads/17`.

I’ve tried setting `=f` to this glob, but that doesn’t help.

(Same question applies to `git log`).

Thank you!

Comment: Using `=f` from the popup is the way to restrict diff and log commands
to a file, but wildcards aren't currently supported.  Please open a
feature request on GitHub.

Comment: @KyleMeyer, thank you! I somehow missed this email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `v2.8.0` Magit supports globbing in paths passed to diff and log commands. (If you use Melpa, then the respective commit is already included now.)