# view git diff version by version

Tags: magit, diff

I'd like to browse the history of a specific file version by version. Ideally, as I step through history I should compare it with the closest previous version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think commands `magit-log-buffer-file` and its variant `magit-log-buffer-file-popup` are what you are looking for. These are bound to `l` and `L` in Magit buffers, respectively. Invoking the former command within a version-controlled-file-visiting buffer (i.e. by typing `M-x magit-log-buffer-file`) skips the popup and displays the log directly. Within the resulting log buffer, you can use keys like `DEL` and `RET` to show/scroll and visit the commit at point, and `n` and `p` to move point back and forth in history, respectively.

Note that you can limit the history to any number of files in both popups using the `=f` option.

#### Edit

See also [tarsius' mention of globbing functionality](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26204/15748) and answers to a [near-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966567/3084001).

#### Addendum

If you enable `magit-file-mode`/`global-magit-file-mode`, then you can access the aforementioned log commands via `magit-file-popup`, which is bound to `C-c M-g` by default. Thus, instead of typing `M-x magit-log-buffer-file` or `M-x magit-log-buffer-file-popup`, you can instead type `C-c M-g l` or `C-c M-g L`, respectively.

Comment: Once I'm in that view for my file how can I see ediff-style side-by-side diffs?

Comment: @m33lky See [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28735/15748).